# WinForm not accepting user input from MySql due to fatal error

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating a WinForm Registration Form and recently switched my entire code to remove SQL Injections I was getting. I can now register users to be stored in my database but I can not user that information to log on.

```
string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=welcome";
string Query = "insert into userdatabase.users (userid, email, passone, passtwo, lastname, firstname) values(@userid,@email,@passone,@passtwo,@lastname,@firstname)";
MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", this.userid_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("passone", this.passone_txt.Text);

try
{
    conDatabase.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to iDSTEM!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

That is the code for my login button, I know that the AddWithValue is not what needs to be there but that is what I currently have to store the values and wanted to know what I should change it to.

Here is my code that stores my data into MySql.

```
string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=welcome";
string Query = "insert into userdatabase.users (userid, email, passone, passtwo, lastname, firstname) values(@userid,@email,@passone,@passtwo,@lastname,@firstname)";

MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", this.userid_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", this.email_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("passone", this.passone_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("passtwo", this.passtwo_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", this.lastname_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", this.firstname_txt.Text);

try {
    conDataBase.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to iDSTEM!");
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

When I run the log in I receive

> Fatal Error encountered during command execution

Thanks in advance for any helps or tips you are able to give me.

Answer (score 1):

To login, you will have to use `SELECT * FROM tbl where username = @userid and password = @password` instead of the insert statement that you've used. (I assume that the first code you've provided is for login). And then, instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, you can use either `ExecuteReader` or `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet`.

You are receiving fatal error because the number of parameters expected in the insert query you wrote for login (6 -> `@userid,@email,@passone,@passtwo,@lastname,@firstname`) and those provided (2 -> `@userid,@passone`) is different.

Comment: I based the login off of my register form so thanks for pointing out the overlooks, I still think where I have 'cmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@userid", this.userid_txt.Text);' is not supposed to me AddWithValue any ideas? @Manish Dalal

Comment: @Bendlino: I think AddWithValue is ok [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx] Also, it seems that using @ with parameter name is optional for mySQL (but its always a better practice to have @ before parameter name)